# Conduit Exercise

Tags: haskell

[conduit](https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit#more-exercises) offers the following exercise:

> Write a conduit that consumes a stream of Ints. It takes the first Int from the stream, and then multiplies all subsequent Ints by that number and sends them back downstream. You should use the mapC function for this.

Here's what I came up with:

```
multiplier :: Monad m => ConduitM Int Int m ()
multiplier = do
  mx <- await
  case mx of
    Nothing -> return ()
    Just x  -> mapC (* x)
```

After reloading the REPL, I ran it:

```
λ: >runConduitPure $ yieldMany [1..5] .| multiplier .| sinkList
[2,3,4,5]
λ: >runConduitPure $ yieldMany [3..5] .| multiplier .| sinkList
[12,15]
λ: >runConduitPure $ yieldMany [] .| multiplier .| sinkList
[]
```

Comment: I've never seen `mx` as name for having your desired `x` wrapped in a `Maybe` - that is genius! Definitely need to do this myself from now on.

Comment: I took it straight from the README! Also, what's so genius about it? I'm not disputing it. I just don't get what mx means!

Comment: Well, your desired variable is called `x`. But what `await` returns is a `Maybe Int`, so you call the "maybe it's my x, maybe it's not" `mx` - maybe x.

Comment: `multiplier = await >>= traverse_ (mapC . (*))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sufficiently solves the exercise, is highly readable and easily maintainable. As Phil said, the "m" prefix for Maybe's is a nice pattern, even if it originates from Conduits README. It's something you can keep for future projects.

There's only a small nitpick: while the exercise tells you to multiply a conduit of integers, it's not necessary for the upstream or downstream values to be integers. Anything that understands `(*)` should work, so we can generalize it's type:

```
multiplier :: (Num a, Monad m) => ConduitM a a m ()
```

Also, we should test a single element list.

---

Gurkenglas' variant will work, as usual, but it depends on whether you like the pointfree style:

```
multiplier = await >>= traverse_ (mapC . (*))
-- vs
multiplier = await >>= traverse_ (\x -> mapC (*x))
-- vs
multiplier = do
  mx <- await
  for_ mx (\x -> mapC (*x))
-- vs
multiplier = do
  mx <- await
  case mx of
    Just x  -> mapC (*x)
    Nothing -> return ()
```

As they are all equivalent, I suggest you to use the one you like the most, and which you will understand even three months later. Your original one is the easiest to read.